# In golang how do I encode an xml parameter containing a space?

Tags: xml, go

I have this xml api construct I need to use (this construct is not defined by me and I cannot change it):

```
<path><farmer id="ME7"/></path>
```

In go I have:

```
type Path struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"path"`
  FarmerId string `xml:"farmer id,attr"`
}

pMux := &Path{FarmerId: "ME7"}
```

However go encodes pMux and prints it as this:

```
<path xmlns:farmer="farmer" farmer:id="ME7" </path>
```

What I want is this:

```
<path><farmer id="ME7"/> </path>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thx

Comment: You can't have an XML element or attribute name with a space in it. That's invalid XML.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear hence why I said "element or attribute name". Neither can have a space in it.

Comment: Well, it's invalid XML altogether because there is no closing tag for `farmer` and it doesn't close itself.

Comment: Can you do `farmer>id,attr`? I don't think so but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Are you sure you want `<path farmer id="ME7" </path>` as posted, or do you want `<path farmer id="ME7"></path>`?

Comment: Generating the desired (pseudo)XML is dead simple by use of fmt.Printf. No need for cleverness if something so simple (and invalid) has to be generated.

Comment: @Volker unless this is just a small piece of a larger piece of XML (which is likely). Attempting to do this as a value of another tag would result in the `<>` being XML encoded. Still hackable though. And this would probably be even more efficient than regexing a large XML string.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear encoding/xml offer solutions for this problem.

Comment: This is what I need. I missed the trailing slash in my post: <farmer id="ME-7000-2"/>      And yes, this is just a tiny snippet of a much larger xml structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML is invalid, but if you really need it to come out like that, use a regular expression to fix it afterward. Here is an example.

I am assuming that you really want the open tag valid like so `<path farmer id="ME7"></path>`, instead of not having the open tag valid as you posted `<path farmer id="ME7" </path>`, but either way is doable with regex.

BTW, your question is inconsistent about what you want. You start with wanting `<path><farmer id="ME7"></path>`, which @eugenioy 's answer will accommodate. Then end with "What I want is this: `<path farmer id="ME7" </path>`". Which my answer is geared toward.

https://play.golang.org/p/A-sJhIgFZW

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

type Path struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"path"`
    Farmer   string   `xml:"farmer,attr"`
    FarmerId string   `xml:"id,attr"`
}

func main() {
    path := &Path{
        FarmerId: "ME7",
    }
    data, err := xml.Marshal(path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    strData := string(data)

    // fix with regex
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`(farmer)(="")`)
    strData = reg.ReplaceAllString(strData, "$1")
    fmt.Println(strData) // <path farmer id="ME7"></path>
}
```

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, I have encountered something very similar to this myself with someones broken API implementation. In my case, I had to forcefully modify the XML to have a self closing tag (which go doesn't support), and had to use a magic string to insert multiple XML namespaces (which go also doesn't support, or didn't at the time).

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid XML.

I would double check the API contract you mention since it's unlikely they require invalid XML.

The closest you can get to that is this valid XML.

```
<path><farmer id="ME7"></farmer></path>
```

In order to generate the above (valid) XML, you should define your types as:

```
type Farmer struct {
   XMLName   xml.Name    `xml:"farmer"`
   Id        string      `xml:"id,attr"`
}

type Path struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"path"`
    Farmer  Farmer   `xml:"farmer"`
}
```

And then create the value as:

```
v := Path{Farmer: Farmer{Id: "ME7"}}
```

See here for a running example: https://play.golang.org/p/abEqMc6HdK

Comment: If the XML must end up invalid exactly as in the example, remove the closing tag with `reg := regexp.MustCompile("(</farmer>)")
 data = reg.ReplaceAllString(data, "")`

Comment: Many thanks. I checked with the api owner again. According to them:  If an XML element contains no value or child element then the element may be closed with “/>”. So from their perspective self termination without a </farmer> tag is legal. I take it golang does not support this type of termination.